# Does #strings.replace() utility method of String object in thymeleaf replaces all occurrences in provided string?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a string as

```
str = My name is john.<br> I am software engineer.<br> I am a web developer<br>
```

I wanted to replace all occurrences that `<br>` with `<br />` in thymeleaf.

I have tried this

```
${#strings.replace(str,'<br>','<br />')}
```

I wanted to know, does above string replace method replace all occurrences of `<br>`?

References:
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-3-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will replace all the occurrences. Thymeleaf internally calls java.lang.String.replace method to replace the the occurrences.